# Rest API: Quering all values from field with versioning

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

is there any way how to query via REST API all values from field with property "Append Changes to Existing Text"?  I am always getting "null" value.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint list.asmx web service there is a method "GetVersionCollection" can get the version history of the multiline field "Appending Changes to Existing Text", check the demo below:

[Work with Multiline Text field versions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29559.sharepoint-hosted-apps-working-with-version-history-of-multiple-lines-of-text-column.aspx)

The method will need list id, item id and the field name, put the valid value of these:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, so it can't be done though REST API, but SPServices is the right way how to get it.